# Rendering footer section in razor pages works cover button from body

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I got problem with my Razor page application. I already use render section for footer:

```
    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        @RenderSection("footer", required: false)
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - EmployeeBook - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

and use it also in employee list

```
@page
@model EmployeeBook.Pages.Employees.EmployeesModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Employees";
}

<h1>Employees razor page</h1>


<br />

<form method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            @*asp-for two ways data binding*@
            <input type="search" class="form-control" asp-for="SearchTerm" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@foreach (var employee in Model.Employees)
{
    <partial name="_Summary" model="employee" />
}

@*Remember about nullable values added to onGet/onPost if we want to use this method there*@
<div>
    <a asp-page="./EditEmployee" class="btn btn-primary">Add nefw Employee</a>
</div>



@section footer {
<div>
    @Model.Message
</div>
}
```

Result of that is something like that:
[image: Unexpected result]

Im trying to use _summary partial view to display details of employees instead of common list. Could someone tell me where the problem can be? I use just classes from bootstrap. It start to works not correct when I add more employees.

```
@using EmployeeBook.Core
@*from lower case define just type of object into view*@
@*from upper case this is model property where we can go into*@
@model Employee

<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>@Model.Name</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <span>Type of employee @Model.TypeOfEmployee</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-light"
           asp-page="./EmployeeDetails"
           asp-route-employeeId="@Model.Id">
            Details
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-light"
           asp-page="./EditEmployee"
           asp-route-employeeId="@Model.Id">
            Edit
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger"
           asp-page="./Delete"
           asp-route-employeeId="@Model.Id">
            Delete
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `It start to works not correct when I add more employees.`Cam you share your `EditEmployee.cshtml` and `EditEmployee.cshtml.cs`?What will it do after add a new Employee?

Comment: I mean that every employee take some place, and if I got it more then the button go to down of the page. Then the problem occurs. It comes to footer and I can't do anything with that...

Comment: You mean you didn't add new employees to the view,only show the view which contains employee list by default,and the footer will cover the button?

Comment: Hi @YiyiYou, I already find problem, it was in css, I just change footer class for new and all works perfect, thanks for answer man !:)

Comment: Can you add some details of how you fix it?